# Is it possible to recover partial compressed files?

Tags: data-recovery, compression, zip, 7-zip, gzip

Of the most popular compression methods (7z, RAR, Zip, GZip) is there any of them that allows to retrieve the uncompressed data from a partial file?

Imagine there is only one compressed file, and it is a plain text log. Would I be able to read some of the log if the compressed file wasn't written to the end?

Comment: Yes its possible.  If the file is not complete you cannot extract the file from the archive.  In order to recover a partial archive Par2 files must exist for the archive.  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAR2

Comment: try it http://www.diskinternals.com/zip-repair